# Why doesn't my Facebook App Requests appear anywhere?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, koala

I'm trying to get app requests to work and failing miserably. I'm using both Koala graph.put_object (for app-to-user) and the JavaScript dialog example by Facebook (for user-to-user). Both works in the sense that I get request IDs back, but I never see the request appear anywhere. I've tried Sandbox mode on/off, adding the recipient user as App Tester, nothing works.

Comment: Is this a canvas app? If not, this is a possible duplicate of http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/9363471/apprequest-for-a-website

Comment: Not a canvas app. Are requests not supported at all for web apps?

Comment: No, only mobile and canvas - this is mentioned on the requests documentation